# Not able to find export for interface Request in express type definition file

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

In Typescript while using express  I am able to export interface "Request" and "Response" from  express without errors

```
import {Request,Response} from "express"
```

For Response I could find the interface Response has been exported in the express type definition file(node_modules@types\express\index.d.ts). ie

```
...
export interface Response<ResBody = any, Locals extends Record<string, any> = Record<string, any>>
....
```

But for interface Request I cant see this interface being exported, I can just see this is declared. Without being exported how is the import working for Request interface without issues?

Comment: `node_modules@types\express\index.d.ts:112`,  `interface Request<`

Comment: yes I can see the Interface in line 112, but only thing is it is not exported